# Is there any major difference between XAMPP and LAMP?

Tags: windows-7, xampp, lamp, ubuntu-10.04

Recently I sent my CV to a small company which required a web developer, but one condition was that I should know how to work with LAMP. So I took part in the contest, but today I started to wonder if those packages are as similar as I think.

So, are they?

I am using: XAMPP (Basispaket) version
1.7.1 on Windows 7 and planning to install LAMP on Ubuntu 10.04 (don't
know the version yet).

UPDATE: I read some articles about LAMP
setup and I only found, that you just
need to separately install Apache,
PHP, and MySQL. I'm confused; so isn't there's
any control panel like in XAMPP? If so,
then I'm asking about those major
differences.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

LAMP is an acronym for Linux (operating system), Apache HTTP Server, MySQL (database software), and PHP. If you're running Windows the acronym is [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants).

XAMPP is a package you can use to easily install and configure a (in your case) WAMP or LAMP setup. If they are asking LAMP they probably expect some Linux and Apache knowledge, but it could also be they are just expecting a PHP programmer with MySQL skills. You'll find out what they're looking for in the job interview ;).

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I thought, that LAMP and XAMPP are one and the same, with one difference, that XAMPP (X - stands for any OS) and LAMP (L - stands for Linux OS). It all goes for WAMP and MAMP as well. No?

Comment: XAMPP is the specific name for the package by Apache Friends (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). LAMP, WAMP, MAMP, SAMP, FAMP, and OpAMP (I'm probably still forgetting some... ;)) are acronyms to indicate a certain web server set-up. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle) for more information.

I'm sure XAMP (note the missing P at the end) is used as a synonym for AMP though. AMP indicating the Apache, MySQL, and PHP (or Perl or Python) stack on top of some OS.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment on the answer below by James Anderson so here's my reply to your follow-up question Eugene.

Yes, it will still be called LAMP. It's just an acronym for a certain combination of software making up your web server stack.

Comment: And do I understad correctly, that LAMP doesn't have a control panel like XAMPP (At least XAMPP under Windows. Don't know about other OS.)?

Comment: Correct. Although you are of course free to install some kind of control panel (like for instance WebMin http://www.webmin.com/). These control panels are usually aimed at managing more than just the LAMP stack though. The term LAMP doesn't really say anything about stuff like control panels, it's just short hand for a certain set-up. Software like XAMPP can help you quickly set up an AMP stack.

Answer (score 6):

LAMP and [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) are generic terms for any Apache web server, MySQL database, and Perl or PHP or Python language, based system.

[XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) is a specific software package that contains all the elements of an *AMP system in a single package. There are several packages like this (WampServer to name one).

The software install process on Ubuntu is so straightforward that many people prefer to install the components individually and run a leaner and meaner setup.

Comment: So if I install them individually, then it still will be LAMP or just individuall packages?

Answer (score 0):

If someone asks about LAMP skills, and you have been using WAMP, it only needs you to learn Linux to make up the stack since there is no complete pack for LAMP as there is with XAMPP and WAMP.

So here the issue is all about your ability to configure the Apache server, the MySQL database with PHP on a Linux system period. Any recruiter will look for that. In fact, since you're considering learning Linux just install [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), dig into it, and go prove to them your LAMP skills.

Comment: Learning Linux for the first time may be a non-trivial gap for some people. The company probably expects to have some of your time just be learning, but maybe not fully allocated to someone who may not have run `ls` before (in general, not sure about OP's knowledge). I'd still apply, at least it will tell you where you are.